# Area of a trapezium inscribed in a circle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

A circle, having center at $(2, 3)$ and radius $6$, crosses $y$-axis at the  points  $P$  and  $Q$.  The  straight  line  with  equation  $x=  1$  intersects the radii $CP$ and $CQ$ at points $R$ and $S$ respectively. Find the area of the trapezium $PQSR$.

I am getting stuck to find the length of parallel  sides?
As area of  a trapezium is $A=\frac{a+b}{2} \cdot h$

here  $a$ = $SR$ , b = $PQ $

How to find $h$?

Comment: Don't delete your question, as the question may be useful to other people with the same question.

Comment: @Toby Mak Why would i delete?

Comment: I have experience with other users that often questions like this.

Comment: By the way, do you own [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/791682/rancho) whose username is Rancho?

Comment: no! I did wrong in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Pythagorean theorem you can find $PQ$.
$$PQ = 2\cdot\sqrt{r^2 - (2h)^2},$$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle, and $h$ is the altitude of the trapezoid $PQSR$.
$$RS = \frac{PQ}{2},$$ because the triangles $PCQ$ and $RCS$ are similar and $PC = 2RC.$
 So you can plug in the values and find the area of the trapezoid by using $A = h\cdot\frac{PQ + RS}{2}$.
$$r = 6, h =\frac{HC}{2} = 1, PH = 4\sqrt 2, PQ = 8\sqrt 2, RS = 4\sqrt 2,$$ 
$$A = 6\sqrt 2$$
[image]

Comment: How can u come to  this geometric picture! By seeing the equation only it is impossible to draw like this

Comment: Simply use the coordinates of the center and the length of $r$ to draw this diagram in a coordinate system.

Comment: By  simple observation how can u tell , Q(0,-3)

Comment: But the coordinates of $Q$ is not (0,-3). It is just illusion of you. $Q$ is a bit above.

Comment: How are u assuming PQ=6? "so the triangle PCQ is equilateral"  how can u conclude that?

Comment: $PQ = 8\sqrt 2$,  not 6.

Comment: U are contradicting yourself. if PQ= 8*2^(1/2) how can be PCQ is equilateral

Comment: Because $PC = QC = r$

Comment: please check your comment. In geometry, an equilateral triangle is a triangle in which all three sides are equal. I dont understand what are u talking about

Comment: Oh sorry I have mixed up equilateral with isosceles

Comment: *$PC = QC = r$, so the triangle $PCQ$ is isosceles.

Comment: thanks for your answer.it is indeed helpful

Comment: I'm sorry for that  mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108445/discussion-between-statistics-and-tigran-harutyunyan).

Answer (score 0):

$h = 1$ since the distance between the $y$-axis ($x=0$) and $x=1$ is $1$. The tricky part is finding $a$ and $b$.

Comment: can u provide the solution.I am getting stuck

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried first? Then others can help you better.

Comment: I have tried,But I am unable to do it.That's why I have posted here

Comment: Well other people aren't likely to answer unless you show some effort on your half. That's the way this site works; ask elsewhere if you want to avoid this problem.

Comment: Oh sorry I have mixed up equilateral with isosceles

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The equation of the circle is $$(x-2)^2 +(y-3)^2 =36$$ To find $P$ and $Q$, set $x=0$ and solve the quadratic in $y$. Now, find the equations of lines $CP$ and $CQ$, and finally set $x=1$ in these equations to find $R$ and $S$. You have everything you need now.

Comment: @Statistics What do you mean by ‘strange’ values?

Comment: sorry.My calculations were wrong! thanks for your answer.it is indeed helpful

Comment: Setting x =1 ; u will never find R and S . U will find the y value which cut the circle at x = 1.Edit your answer.

Comment: @Statistics Finding the $y$ value is indirectly finding $R$ and $S$ themselves, it should be obvious.

Comment: No. How can u find R and S value after finding (1,y1) & (1,y2)?

Comment: According to me u have to find the eq using y-y1 = m(x-x1) which also will support R and S ,in this way u have to proceed.Did u mean that?

Comment: @Statistics Yes. R and S **are** precisely $(1,y_1)$ and $(1,y_2)$. No need to do anything else.

Comment: R value can never be (1,y1) the y value of R will be less than y1,same goes to S also

Comment: @ Tavish No, at x = 1 u are getting , y^2-6y-26 = 0 ,upon solving the values u get of y that 'll intersect the circle not CP and CQ. check once more.U will get it

Comment: @Statistics I never told you to put $x=1$ in the equation of the circle. If you read carefully, it says put $x=1$ in the equation of the *lines* $CP$ and $CQ$.

Comment: i was also saying that. after finding the eqn of CP and CQ u have to put x =1 there,then u will get the required co-ordinates.

Comment: @Statistics So what’s the problem? The answer I wrote was correct and you just misread it.